# How to get the equivalement primitive types from an object of java.lang type in Java?

Tags: java

Now is there an easy way to do so? Let's say that I have an Object that could be Long, Float, Integer, Byte, etc, how do I get its equivalelent primitive class (Class) from this object?

A method could be written like this

```
Class<?> getEquivalentPrimitiveType(Object obj)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The corresponding primitive type is [`Long.TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#TYPE):

> `public static final Class<Long> TYPE`
>
> The Class instance representing the primitive type `long`.

If you have an instance of a "wrapper" class, you can get the corresponding primitive through reflection, like this:

```
static <T> Class<T> getPrimitive(Class<T> wrapper)
    throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    return (Class<T>)wrapper.getDeclaredField("TYPE").get(null);
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/Wy93Gd).

Comment: After rethinking, this is actually not what I meant. I guess that I have to build a map from java.lang types to built-in types. 
Please see edited question

Comment: @imgen You can also get it through reflection by accessing the `TYPE` field of the corresponding wrapper type.

Comment: As a reference, you can see there : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html